# Performing ng-click AND ng-switch on angular form submit

Tags: forms, angularjs

I have a single page angular app. The landing page is a signin form with a link to a sign up form. The rest of the app is not visible until the user has been authenticated. I swop the signin and signup pages using the ng-switch directive. So when the signin form loads and the user clicks the "sign up" button, the ng-switch directive swops the signup partial for the signin partial. I need to perform a "createAccount()" function and do an ng-switch back to the signin partial on submission of the signup form. Is this possible? Right now, when I click on submit, it just does the ng-switch and ignores the createAccount() bit.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-switch on="view.controller">

    <div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" ng-switch-default ng-controller="UserCtrl">

        <div ng-show="!isAuthenticated">
            <form class = "form-signin">

                <div class="control-group">

                    <div class="controls">
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder = "Email Address" > 
                    </div>

                    <br />
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder = "Password" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button class = "btn btn-primary" ng-click="signIn()">Sign In</button>


                        <button class = "btn btn-default" ng-click= "view.controller = 'AccountNewCtrl'" >Register</button>

                    </div> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


<!--Start of sign up form-->

    <div ng-switch-when="AccountNewCtrl" >
        <div ng-controller = "AccountNewCtrl" >
            <div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" ng-show="!isAuthenticated">

                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Sign Up<br />

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">

                    <form id = "myForm" name="myForm" ng-submit="createAccount()"> 

//Form input code here      


//On clicking this button, the createAccount() function should happen and then the     ng-click event should happen 
                        <button type="submit" ng-click= "view.controller = 'UserCtrl'" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Register</button>

                    </form>
            </div>    
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your createAccount() function you could do

```
$scope.$parent.view.controller = 'UserCtrl';
```

That way you don't need the `ng-click` on the submit button on the registration form.